# Adding an implicit getAs() method to Scala Maps

Tags: scala, implicit

So I want to add an implicit method which would return the value for a key by checking its type.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object MyMap {
  implicit class FlexMap[A](map: Map[String, A]) {
    def getAs[B](key: String)(implicit ct: ClassTag[B]): Option[B] = map.get(key) match {
      case Some(value: ct.runtimeClass) => Some(value.asInstanceOf[B])
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try and compile this, I get:

> type runtimeClass is not a member of scala.reflect.ClassTag[B]

I get the same error even if I use:

```
case Some(value) if (value.isInstanceOf[ct.runtimeClass])
```

I am not sure how to get around this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Scala a type is not a value, they are in different categories, so type can't be returned from a method. `.runtimeClass` in fact returns a value of type `Class` which can't be used where a type is expected. What you probably need is this:

```
object MyMap {
  implicit class FlexMap[A](map: Map[String, A]) {
    def getAs[B](key: String)(implicit ct: ClassTag[B]): Option[B] = map.get(key) match {
      case Some(value: B) => Some(value)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

Another way of saying the same thing:

```
def getAs[B](key: String)(implicit ct: ClassTag[B]): Option[B] = 
  map.get(key) flatMap {
    case value: B => Some(value)
    case _        => None
  }
```

Comment: This compiles, but Scala fails to interpret an `Any` as an `Int`. Maybe it's expected behavior, but what do I do to make it work. This is what I mean. `Map[String, Any]("foo" -> 1).getAs[Int]("foo")` gives back `None`.

Comment: Your snippet returns `Option[Int] = Some(1)` for me (2.11.8)

Comment: Looks like it's not working for 2.10 but is for 2.11.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassTag` has an `unapply` method which does the actual casting work for you, and returns an option.

```
implicit class FlexMap[A](map: Map[String, A]){                                                        
  def getAs[B](key: String)(implicit ct: ClassTag[B]): Option[B] = 
    map.get(key).flatMap(ct.unapply)     
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what Scala is doing under the hood in my example expanding `case`. I wonder should it be considered too "low level"?

Comment: This compiles, but Scala fails to interpret an `Any` as an `Int`. Maybe it's expected behavior, but what do I do to make it work. This is what I mean. `Map[String, Any]("foo" -> 1).getAs[Int]("foo")` gives back `None`.

Comment: Ah, I guess there are some weird semantics with `AnyVal` types and `ClassTag`'s unapply. I'll have to do some poking around to solve this.